# Can you and should you store table names in a table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm creating an app where 1 user will be monitoring the progress of another user. This monitor can change over time, so I want to build in a notes taking process. Each monitored user would have a collection of notes associated with them that future monitors could review.

I want each user to have their own notes table though because I am afraid that if there are a huge number of notes with different users, looking things up will be hectic.

My thinking is, if I store all the notes in 1 table, each with the `user_id` as the foreign key, if I ever have to look up all the notes for 1 user I have to search the entire table. Where as, if each has their own table I can know exactly where all the notes for that particular user are located. 
 The ways I'm approaching this is to have one table users:

```
User_Monitored
--------
+user_id
...
```

and another separate table that is specific to the monitored user, supposing there'd be lots of these

```
User_Monitored_Notes_(id)
--------------------
+note_id
+note
```

and a 3rd table in-between that references each user and what table they're associated with

```
Intermediary_Table
-----------------
+user_id
+User_Monitored_Notes_(id)
```

Is there a better way I should go about this? I feel like having a table know something directly about the database structure is a no no.

Comment: Table knowing about structure - yes, that's a bad idea, but `I want each user to have their own notes table` is even more bizarre, can you explain what has led you down this route of thinking. Feels like there is a hidden requirement

Comment: No, no, no, no, no!!! That is a terrible idea. And with proper indexes looking up data of a table with millions of records is super fast and no problem at all

Comment: You normally should not need this, and to even take advantage of the table names would require using dynamic SQL, again something which you probably should not have to resort to.

Comment: " I am afraid that if there are a huge number of notes". How many do you expect? databases have millions... billions of rows and this is not a problem. You'll waste far more time if you use the anti-pattern you want to use as opposed to waiting for some records to come back if you model it properly by using one table.

Comment: I can only re-iterate what the others have written: don't do it. Create a single `notes` table with a `user_id` column indicating the user to which the notes belong. You can always think about partitioning the table (how efficient that is depends on the DBMS you are using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one table, and can add an index of user_id for performance if you need.  Returning a result set from millions of rows will be measured in milliseconds.

note_id | user_id | note

Even if you did use separate tables, the ID for your table name would be stored in User_Monitored -- there would be no need to duplicate it.

If you do want a reference to the tables in your database, it is already built automatically and you can use it to determine if a table exists.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
```